# Is it possible to use waterproof grout + sealer to fix shower room floor leaks?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, grout

I believe the leakage is at the two corners near the curb. If I pour water to two corners, there will be leakage to first floor. My guess is when the remodeler tiled the shower room floor, they broke the shower pan.

My question is if I remove all the existing grout, and apply waterproof grout, then use grout sealer to treat several times, is that enough to stop water leakage?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  If it does, I doubt it will be a viable long-term fix.  Do it right, tear it out, replace the broken or leaking shower pan, and redo the tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the existing grout, and re-grout with an epoxy grout. It's more expensive than regular grout but it's completely waterproof and you won't need too seal it. It's also much stronger than regular grout.

However, if in fact the shower pan is broken, then this will probably be a temporary fix and you'll know when it fails because the leak will start again. A permanent solution would be to rip up the tile, replace or repair the pan and re-tile and grout. good luck